# Changing schema of panda's dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this [image: input dataframe]

And I want the output to be like:

[image: output]

I have gone through some similar problems, which uses table_pivot method to convert column vales to column and doing aggregation for the values. But that requirement is not suiting my problem definition.

Being new to pandas dataframe, having hard time to understand how to get this output.

Any suggestions would help me.

Comment: Can you add your `pivot_table` solution? Because I think here should working well.

Comment: Also there are some error? Please add to question.

Comment: df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['flat',  'CurrentBill', 'CurrentPay',  'forecastedBill',  'forecastedPay'], columns=['year'])

Comment: error: pandas.core.base.DataError: No numeric types to aggregate

Comment: Try `df = pd.pivot_table(df, index=['flat', 'CurrentBill', 'CurrentPay'], values=['forecastedBill', 'forecastedPay'], columns=['year'])` and then flatten values `df.columns = [f'{a}{b}' for a,b in df.columns]`